# Getting an image from an RSS feed, using syndication?

Tags: c#, regex, image, windows-phone-7, rss

I am building a Windows Phone app and using `SyndicationFeed` to read an RSS feed. How do I get the picture from the feed?

Will I need a converter(?), but I don't know what will go in it. I saw there is an `ImageUrl` property and I tried putting that in use but no joy. :(

The pictures need to be filtered by the category together with the feed (which is predefined). I know how to get the feed filtered (generous forum member helped :) )
just getting images is the problem.

I'm using an MSDN example as a background: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487167(v=vs.92).aspx

My feed: http://www.zimo.co/feed/

---

I would use this regex to get the images from the feed:

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"<img.*?src=""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but the problem is how to implement it. so I get the feed and the picture at the same time  :(

this is the code I use:

```
private void UpdateFeedList(string feedXML)
    {
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(feedXML);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);


Regex rg = new Regex(@"<img.*?src=""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {

ls_text.ItemsSource = feed.Items;


        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the* picture?  You may have to parse the content of the feed item to find a picture you want to display.  There's not an element in the feed for a picture.

Comment: So U are telling me I have to write additional code which will parse xml and extract picture?

Comment: what info do I get with syndication regarding picture?

Comment: Look at the xml.  What you see is what you get.

Comment: I did but it puzzles me what to write in the xaml in <image name="img" source="???"> </image>
U know to reach the picture like u pull the title or the description from the feed.
Im a fresh programmer so its a bit all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the RSS specification that provides for a singular image that represents the `<item>` being processed.  If you want to have an image, you can try parsing the `<content>` element and pulling out one or more images from the element contents.

To get the image links out of the source, you're going to need to parse the text  to get a match of all `<img>` tags in the text.  You can try to do this in a couple ways.  You could try to do a RegEx match of the img tags, or you could try to load the text into an XML document and parse it.  The problem is, it's not full HTML, so you might have to modify it a bit (for example, you *might* have to put an enclosing set of tags around the content, if the content isn't already enclosed by `<p>` tags.

Comment: Any idea where to start? Can I even use the feed I get with syndication for parsing or do I need to write a new code. because I have to filter by category later both feed & pictures.